# Display empty weeks through groupby for a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I applied groupby on my dataframe with columns `Description`, `Week` and `Count` to get weekly count which looks something like this:

                                            `Description       Week  count
527                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-05-03     77
528                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-05-10    983
529                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-05-17    245
530                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-05-24    897
531                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-05-31   2144
532                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-06-07    926
533                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-06-14   1082
534                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-06-21   1935
535                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-06-28   1511
536                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-07-05   3206
537                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-07-12   2031
538                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-07-19    590
539                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-07-26   1085
540                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-08-02    162
541                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-08-09    922
542                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-08-16    655
543                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-08-23    114
544                      N25846 External EMERGENCY STOP 2015-08-30     42
616                        N38 Excessive servo lag in Z 2015-08-23      1
676                     N418 Program start undefined 11 2015-08-23      1
679                 N4226 8BD0 Excessive servo lag in V 2015-08-23      1
680                 N4226 8BD0 Excessive servo lag in Y 2015-08-23      1
681                 N4226 8BD0 Excessive servo lag in Z 2015-08-23      1
762                               N51 Positioning error 2015-08-23      1
1471                         P69 Tool magazine error# 3 2015-08-23      1
1567                 P795 0-SIGNAL LUBRICATION FEEDBACK 2015-08-23      1
1908  Powerfail AC, HDD lock:15.08.2015 01:32:40.533... 2015-08-23      1
1976              number of missing logbook entries: 18 2015-08-23      1
175                                N156 MP: not defined 2015-08-30      1`

Reaching towards the end, we see that the empty weeks aren't displayed. Is there a way to display the empty weeks for each `Description` with count 0 for the weeks it hasn't appeared?

Required output:

`Description          Week          count
N156 MP: not defined 2015-05-03     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-05-10     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-05-17     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-05-24     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-05-31     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-06-07     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-06-14     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-06-21     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-06-28     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-07-05     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-07-12     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-07-19     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-07-26     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-08-02     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-08-09     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-08-16     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-08-23     0
N156 MP: not defined 2015-08-30     1`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 'empty weeks' are missing values (?). The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#na-values-in-groupby) say

> NA groups in GroupBy are automatically excluded.

If this is the reason, you would need to apply `.fillna(value)` prior to `.groupby()` with a *value* of your choice - for instance 0.

Comment: My data has only one entry for `N156 MP: not defined`. It appears only once in the entire data, is there way to impute zeros for it for the days/weeks it didn't appear.

Comment: You could experiment with something like `df = df.set_index(['Description', 'Week').unstack('Description').fillna(0).stack('Description')`.